# how to create Widget in android?

Tags: android, widget

I want to create a widget to show all online users really it's easy to do this in android app 
but I wanna create a widget

is there any way to do this ?

[image]

```
public class WatchWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        RemoteViews remoteViews;
        ComponentName watchWidget;
        java.text.DateFormat format = SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstance(
                SimpleDateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.getDefault());

        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_main);
        watchWidget = new ComponentName(context, WatchWidget.class);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView,
                "Time = " + format.format(new Date()));
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(watchWidget, remoteViews);
    }

}
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: yeah I have a problem with how to set data !

Comment: use custom adapter set data, see this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: yeah shayan that's right what about Update function 

I don't know why my update function not working

android:updatePeriodMillis="10000"

Comment: what is this? where is this? post your code that all user can help you

Comment: look shayan this is my update function code I used this code for making an watchWidget but my watch not updating and stuck at one time